# How to get this quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/The_Litany_of_Larceny#Larceny_trophies

Is there a way to really get this quest? There is no such option when I talked to Delvin.

However, if I do other quest and I see an item, I took it and I can sell it to Delvin.

However, there is no quest that says, okay take queen bee statue for example.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

This quest is **unmarked**, which means while it is tracked as a quest internally by the game, it does not show up in the main quest journals nor can you view completed objectives.

So the behavior you've observed -- no quest text or objectives -- is the correct, default behavior.

Quoting from the [UESP](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Miscellaneous_Quests):

> The actual name of the quest is not visible in game (the names used on this site are the names assigned to the quest in the Creation Kit). Only the current objective associated with the quest can be seen — completed objectives are not displayed, nor is any additional information about the quest stage.

Comment: What are unmarked quests? I can't find it in wiki. Is this the only one

Comment: @user4951 Long story short, it is not. I added more info and a link to the UESP.

Comment: But that is not even in the miscellaneous quest. Miscellaneous quests are normal.

Comment: Also litany of larceny is not one of those miscellaneous quest?