# What are unmarked quests?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In [How to get this quest?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376097/how-to-get-this-quest/376100#376100) I asked why I don't get the quest.

The answer is that the quest is unmarked.

I tried to find some info on wiki about unmarked quests. But I found none. Are there other unmarked quests?

How does unmarked quests work?

Answer (score 1):

Skyrim contains a number of unmarked quests and locations. These are hidden and will only reveal themselves upon discovery of a certain area or after collecting a certain amount of items.

More here:

https://screenrant.com/skyrim-hidden-quests-experts-find-tips-hins/

and here:

https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unmarked_Locations_(Skyrim)